# Non destructive copy of list

Tags: python, python-3.x

how would I create a non destructive copy of a list using b = a[:] ?

Comment: You have two print statements. You should remove the first print, and just call the function instead: `insert_black_tiles(board, 2)`

Comment: @Lawrence my print statements are testing the function...they don't fix why board is changing (even though I made a non destructive copy)

Answer (score 2):

Replace `new_board = board[:]` with:

```
new_board = [x[:] for x in board]
```

`board` is a list of mutable lists.  `board[:]` makes a copy of `board` but does not make a copy of the mutable lists that it contains.  The above code makes those copies.

Alternatively, use the `copy` module (`import copy`):

```
new_board = copy.deepcopy(board)
```

Comment: now it's not working for 8 (see edit).  I'm only getting 6 of the tiles to change black

Answer (score 1):

list_[:] does a copy of the first level list, not the 2nd level lists within it.

Two get both (all, really) levels, try copy.deepcopy(list_).

Comment: now it's not working for 8 (see edit). I'm only getting 6 of the tiles to change black

Answer (score 0):

I've got it to work with

```
def insert_black_tiles(board, num_black_spaces):
    new_board = board[:]
    while num_black_spaces > 0:
        a = random.randint(0,2)
        b = random.randint(0,2)
        c = 'black'
        if new_board[a][b] != 'black':
            new_board[a][b] = c
            num_black_spaces -= 1
    return new_board
```

In your version sometimes a black space get's black a second time.

edit: This is another variant with a library function:

```
def insert_black_tiles(board, num_black_spaces):
    new_board = [x[:] for x in board]
    three_by_three = [(i,j) for i in range(3) for j in range(3)]
    for (a,b) in random.sample(three_by_three, 8):
        new_board[a][b] = 'black'
    return new_board
```

Answer (score 0):

Although other people's answers are far better about the semantics of how the deep-vs-shallow. I would mention that it's generally better style (in my opinion) to use:

`a = list(b)`

rather than

`a = b[:]`

as it's a little more explicit.